# Laravel eloquent attempting to query two wherse or where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have a table with multiple columns.
Two of which I want to query: `product_tag` && `order_date`

What I want to achieve is to query where product_tag equals either `Production One` or `Production Two` AND order_date equals `08-10-2021`

Query I've tried:

```
   $ordersInDB = Products_Order::where('product_tag', 'Production One')
    ->where('order_date', '08-10-2021')
    ->orWhere('product_tag', 'Production Two')
    ->get();
```

The above gets me all Production Two ignoring the two above.
Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You should always group orWhere calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```php
$ordersInDB = Products_Order::where('product_tag', 'Production One')
    ->whereDate('order_date', '2021-10-08')
    ->whereIn('product_tag', ['Product One', 'Production Two'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I used this with slight modification.  I'm going to mark it as correct but here is my update.          $ordersInDB = Products_Order::where('order_date', $orderDate)
        ->whereIn('product_tag', ['Product One', 'Proudct Two'])
        ->get();

Answer (score 1):

You should group orWhere clauses to get the needed data

```
 $ordersInDB = Products_Order::where('order_date', '08-10-2021')
   ->where(function($query){
   $query->where('product_tag', 'Production One')
   ->orWhere('product_tag', 'Production Two');
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `whereIn()`

```
$ordersInDB = Products_Order::whereDate('order_date', '2021-10-08')
    ->whereIn('product_tag', ['Product One', 'Production Two'])
    ->get();
```

or I would suggest querying directly in DB first

```
SELECT * FROM products_order WHERE DATE(order_date) = '2021-10-08' AND  product_tag IN ('Product One', 'Production Two')
```